# Exception in scala when defining my own toInt method

Tags: scala, exception

Why does this code throw an exception?

```
val x = new { def toInt(n: Int) = n*2 }
x.toInt(2)
scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$TypeError: too many arguments for method toInteger: (x$1: java.lang.Object)java.lang.Integer
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context.error(Contexts.scala:298)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.error(Infer.scala:207)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.errorTree(Infer.scala:211)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.tryNamesDefaults$1(Typers.scala:2350)
        ...
```

I'm using scala 2.9.1.final

Comment: Since it's a compiler bug, I recommend making Scala better by filing a bug report in [Scala's issue tracker](https://issues.scala-lang.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly a compiler bug (the compiler crashes, and REPL tells you `That entry seems to have slain the compiler.`). It's not signalling there's anything wrong with your code.

You're creating a single instance of type `AnyRef{def toInt(n: Int): Int}`, so creating a singleton object as Kyle suggests might be  a better way of going about it. Or create a named class / trait that you insantiate, which works fine.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** As Luigi Plinge suggested, it's a compiler bug.

Maybe you want something like this...

```
object x { 
   def toInt(n:Int) = n * 2
}

scala> x.toInt(2)
res0: Int = 4
```

Comment: What do you mean by "scalas toInt"? new {} doesn't have a toInt method that I could override. There is only the toInt method that I defined.